# How do I list all schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-9.1

When using PostgreSQL v9.1, how do I list all of the schemas using SQL?

I was expecting something along the lines of:

```
SELECT something FROM pg_blah;
```

Answer (score 435, accepted):

To lists all schemas, use the (ANSI) standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata;
```

More details in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)

alternatively:

```
select nspname
from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
```

More details about pg_catalog in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html)

Answer (score 439):

When using the `psql` command line, you may list all schema with command `\dn`.

Comment: Thanks.  It would be nice to have just the schemas returned by \dn, but in this case I'm writing a bootstrap app that connects using libpq/libpqxx, so I don't have CLI access.

Comment: what *are* schemas, that `\dn` lists, as opposed to tables that `\dt` lists?

Comment: @Tommy `\dt` lists tables for public schema. To show tables of all schemas use `\dt *.*` and for a particular schema use `\dt schema_name.*`.

Comment: @Tommy, schemas are namespaces: you may have different tables with same name in different namespaces.

Answer (score 67):

Connect to the psql with command `psql --username={userName} {DBName}` then you can type the below command to check how many schemas are present in the database:

```
DBName=# \dn
```

Else you can check the syntax by the below steps easily:

1. After connecting the the DB, type

   ```
    DBName=# help
   ```

   You will get the below options:

   > You are using psql, the command-line interface to PostgreSQL.
   > Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
   > \h for help with SQL commands
   > ? for help with psql commands
   > \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
   > \q to quit
2. Then type

   ```
    DBName=# \?
   ```

   You will get all the options very easily.

Comment: `psql --u login` is wrong CLI attribute, you should use `psql --username=login` or `psql -U login`

Answer (score 34):

Beginning On postgres 9.3, One trick you can use in postgres to get the exact sql of informational command (such as \d, \du, \dp, etc) in psql is by using a transaction.
Here's how the trick goes.
Open one postgres session, then type your command :

```
begin;
\dn+
```

While the transaction still running, open another postgres session, and query the pg_stat_activity and you can get the exact sql.

```
postgres=# select query from pg_stat_activity ;
                                 query                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",                                          +
   pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner",                 +
   pg_catalog.array_to_string(n.nspacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",+
   pg_catalog.obj_description(n.oid, 'pg_namespace') AS "Description" +
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n                                       +
 WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'      +
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: You don't need to trick it; just run `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`

Comment: or run it as `psql -E`

Answer (score 0):

These list all schemas including system's in the current database:

```
\dnS
```

```
\dn *
```

These list all schemas including system's in the current database in detail:

```
\dnS+
```

```
\dn+ *
```

This lists all schemas excluding system's in the current database:

```
\dn
```

This lists all schemas excluding system's in the current database in detail:

```
\dn+
```

These also list all schemas including system's in the current database:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_namespace;
```

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata;
```